# VueJS is copying data from previous JSON node on push()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm facing a weird issue on VueJS.

The API give me a JSON like this:

```
{
  movies: [
    {
      name: "Name 2",
      cover: "cover_image.jpg",
      chars: [
        {
          name: "Character 1",
          picture: "picture.jpg"
        },
        {
          name: "Character 2",
          picture: "picture.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Name 1",
      cover: "cover_image.jpg",
      chars: [
        {
          name: "Character N",
          picture: "picture.jpg"
        },
        {
          name: "Character Z",
          picture: "picture.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using this JSON to populate a few boxes on screen. Note that each node has a sub-node.
All working so far.

When I `push()` a new object into the JSON, the new box appears correctly on page but it's copying the sub-node of previous node. So the Movie 3 is displaying its correct main infos (name and cover) but is copying the characters of Movie 2.

When I refresh the page it's all fine.
Testing API through Postman it's fine as well.

Maybe it could be some cache of VueJS?
I'm using components to display each box.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you binding a unique key for each list item? Showing your code when you render this list would help.

Comment: Unlikely that it is Vue caching. Can you paste the code where you `push()` it into the array?

Comment: It's just `movies.push( new_movie_object );`.

Comment: @moreirapontocom what are the contents of new_movie_object ?  only when you provide relevant  details for debugging your issue will get solved.